# folder "__MACOSX " creating problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Folder "__MACOSX" creating problem.

I am doing something with my document directory folders , but there "__MACOSX" folder create problem .

when user download application from app store . is it creating also in document directory ?
if its creating then what is the solution to solve this ?
please help.

Comment: I am listing Folders from my application directory . and in this folder I am getting one more folder name that is  "__MACOSX" I dont want this in my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to create a blacklist of files or file patterns that you should ignore. A lot of programs have to do this, because it is not uncommon for operating systems to create extraneous files that the user will not care about (e.g. ".DS_Store", "Thumbs.db", "whatever.bak", etc.). You cannot prevent the OS or other programs from creating extra, secret book-keeping or garbage files -- not without potentially breaking things, so just leave them be and remember to ignore them.