# Creating zip with __MACOSX/.DS_Store from a non-mac system

Tags: macos, zip, cross-platform, file-format

There are plenty of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924236/mac-zip-compress-without-macosx-folder) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698399/folder-macosx-creating-problem) about how to ignore the __MACOSX/.DS_Store files created by Mac OS X...

I would like to know how to go the other way, and *include* the __MACOSX/.DS_Store files, specifically when working with zip files created on another platform. Simply zipping up the file structure is not enough; it seems that there is some kind of hidden flag in the zip file that is marking that part of the file structure in the zip as the mac resource fork.

Creating the resource fork on the other platform isn't the issue, I'm specifically trying to generate a zip file that properly includes already existing resources. Any thoughts? Will I need to create my own zip tool?

Comment: I've found this way to do it with Python: [http://knzl.de/creating-a-zip-with-a-folder-icon-for-os-x/]

Comment: Note that the above doesn't fully solve the problem as it only works on the Mac OS.